# What gravity/atmosphere would be needed to allow chunks of land to float inside a planet's atmosphere like in the Manga "One Piece"?

Tags: science-based, biology, planets, physics

It's a fantasy setting, and the world is crazy, but has anyone tried to science it? Weather patterns that are unstable only around what are essentially the Equator and the Greenwich, that change frequently; chunks of just land hanging around in the middle of the sky; people who "kick the air" so hard that they can run in it; vast ranges in size for all creatures without apparent health issues; feats of superhuman strength from human beings.  All that stuff's normal for them. Why?

What's so different about their planet that this works? The atmosphere? Gravity? The number of moons?

"One Piece" here refers to the manga by Oda. [One Piece Wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/One_Piece_Wiki) The chunk of floating land refers to part of a place called [Skypiea](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Skypiea).

The question is specifically asking about the physics behind:

**What gravity/atmosphere would be needed to allow chunks of land to float inside a planet's *lower* atmosphere?**

And by float, I mean staying at a set distance from the surface for 400+ years without destroying life on the surface.

Comment: This is a duplicate indeed.

Comment: @Ekaen, StephenG: I'm asking if it's possible with in the lower atmosphere- without the planet being destroyed.

Comment: @NottheletterA It worked in one piece because they had different types of clouds that could actually support humans and the island was blasted there. Using a fantasy land as a reference and then asking about the physics doesn't make any sense since many aspects of fantasy violate laws of physics even if they are believable.